# If $H , K \trianglelefteq F_2$ with $F_2/H\cong F_2/K$ then $H=K$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism, free-groups, quotient-group

This is probably a basic fact of group theory but I am not able to prove it:

> Let $F_2$ be the free group generated by 2 elements and $H,K$ be two normal subgroups of $F_2$. If $F_2/H$ is isomorphic to $F_2/K$ then $H$ must be equal to $K$.

Any help would be apreciated.

Comment: @Surb $F_2$ is a free group, not the field of order 2

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $F_2$ be generated by $\{x,y\}$ and let $H=\langle\langle x\rangle\rangle$ and $K=\langle\langle y\rangle\rangle$ be the normal closures of $x$ and $y$ respectively. Denote by $\bar{y}$ this image of $y$ in $F_2/H$, and similarly $\bar{x}$ the image of $x$ in $F_2/K$. Then $F_2/H=\langle\bar{y}\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}\cong\langle \bar{x}\rangle=F_2/K$ but $H\neq K$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe I should put $H\cong K$ instead of $H$ equals to $K?.

Comment: That's a very different question. Every subgroup of a free group is free, so up to isomorphism is determined by its rank. This can be any natural number, or countably infinite (uncountable is not possible since the cardinality of $F_2$ is countable). Thus to find a counter example you'd need to find a group $G$ which can be written in two different ways as a quotient of $F_2$ by normal subgroups of different ranks. I don't know if such a $G$ exists. I strongly suspect it can exist for $F_n$, $n>2$, but sometimes $F_2$ can be special.

Comment: Would it be ok to describe the groups $H$ and $K$ as kernels of the two homomorphisms $f_x,f_:F_2\to(\Bbb{Z},+)$ defined by the requirements that they map $x$ and $y$ to $1$ and $0$ respectively, in the two possible orders. Normal closures are fine, I suppose, but kernels of homomorphisms may be more common :-). +1, ofc.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Sure, they are completely equivalent formulations so it's personal preference. As the question was phrased in terms just of normal subgroups I thought it more in-keeping to use normal closures :)